# what does it mean when a function is used as left operand in C++

Tags: c++, ns2, operand

I'm working with NS2 that is in C++ language.
I see the following code that I cannot understand it !!!!

```
ch->size() += IP_HDR_LEN;
```

thanks for your help...

Comment: The function call returns something that can be incremented with `+=`. It would be an lvalue reference to something.

Comment: depends on what ch->size() returns, could be a pointer, lvalue, reference etc.. what don't you understand it clearly looks like it is adding the length of an IP header length

Comment: Find the type of `ch`, and show the declaration of the .size() function. Probably it returns a reference to a member variable

Comment: Usually this means the `size()` function returns a reference to an internal member of `ch` whatever type this should be.

Comment: size() function return the size of packets, I didn't know that it's possible to use functions as the left operand !!!!

Comment: The code is *not* using a function as the left-hand operand; it's using the *return value* from the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `ch->size()` returns *reference* (lvalue) to something which is used in an expression.

For example:

```
class A{
 int x;
 public:
  int& getX(){ return x;}
};
```

then it can be used as

```
A* a= new A;
a->getX() +=5; // which is equivalent to x+=5 or x=x+5, since getX returns reference to 'x', it can be used as LHS of an expression
```

So for your question:

> what does it mean when a function is used as left operand in C++

Here **the return value** is used as *left operand*, not the *function*. The return type is a *reference* to *something*, which represents *lvalue*, and can be used as LHS.

**Edit**

As pointed out by @dlf, `size()` can return an object (by reference or by value) of any class which overloads `operator +=`. If *returned by reference*, then it is same as the above example ( just `int x` becomes `MyClass x`, `int& getX()` becomes `MyClass& getX()` ). If *returned by value*, although one can, but of no use or lead to bad design ( if `MyClass`s `operator +=` changes some global state).

Comment: You are almost certainly correct about `size()` returning an lvalue reference. But if you want to be really pedantic about it (and hey, who doesn't?), it could be returning a class type that overloads `operator +=` too.

Comment: @dlf, I guess the answer covers it. You can just replace `int x` to `MyClass x`. Although one can return by *value*, instead of *reference*, it is of no use ( but one can, +1 for this).

Comment: Your answer's fine. Like I said, just being pedantic :). The only possible "use" I can imagine for having the class object returned by value is if the overloaded += changed global/static state. That would be a horrible design, but I've seen worse!